# Replace fragment in one tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I have 2 tabs. In one of the tabs, there is a fragment (say fragment1) with a grid view of items. If user clicks on the grid item, new fragment (say fragment2) needs to appear, adding the old one in back stack. But I'm  stumbling over replacing fragment. On click, same fragment1 appears again.

activity_home.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="in.brewtv.activities.HomeActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        ...>
            ...
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

HomeActivity.class

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return MyFeedFragment.newInstance();
            case 1:
                return CategoriesFragment.newInstance();
        }
        return null;
    }
    ...
```

CategoriesGridDataAdapter.class:

```
CategoriesItemsRowHolder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Fragment newFragment = SingleCategoryFragment.newInstance(category);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = ((Activity) mContext).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.categories_recycler_view_layout, newFragment ); // give your fragment container id in first parameter
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);  // if written, this transaction will be added to backstack
        transaction.commit();
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I correct this?